# How to hide grouped category in highchart

Tags: javascript

Hi guys thanks a lot for your support, I have following code of highchart, everything working fine but there are 2 categories, I want to show only one but I want to keep its data in tooltip so is there any way to hide first category and show one of them. I have also commented in the code what I want. any help will be appreciated. thanks

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: "container",
        type: "line",
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: '#e8eaeb',
        borderRadius: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            'fontSize': '1em'
        },
        useHTML: true,
        x: -27,
        y: 8,
        text: '<span class="chart-title"> Grouped categories <span class="chart-href"> <a href="http://www.blacklabel.pl/highcharts" target="_blank"> Black Label </a> </span> <span class="chart-subtitle">plugin by </span></span>'
    },
    series: [{
            name:"Low",
        data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
    }],
    xAxis: {        
        categories: [{
            name: "20",//should not hide this
            categories: ["21", "22", "23","24"],
            // I want to do hide this categories:["21", "22", "23","24"]
        }, {
            name: "25", //should not hide this
            categories: ["26", "27", "28","29"]
            // I want to do hide this categories:["26", "27", "28","29"]
        }, {
            name: "30",// //should not hide this
            categories: ["31", "32", "33","34"]
            // I want to do hide this categories:["31", "32", "33","34"]
        }]
    }
});
```

});